# Integral Test can it be used here

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Can we apply integral test on

Series with $(1-n)/2n^2$

First thing I did was to take $-1/2$ outside

So we have

$$(-1/2)\sum((n-1)/n^2)$$

I'm not sure how to follow up later although I know for sure this series will diverge

Can someone help to prove its decreasing too

Comment: Have you actually tried to apply the integral test to this series? What happens when you integrate the general term of the series? (BTW, the series is increasing, not decreasing - but it is decreasing in magnitude.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the comparison test for sequences with $1/n$? The integral-based solution ultimately makes use of the comparison test for integrals with $\int dx/x$.

Comment: Does that mean I cant use it since its increasing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply it:$$\int_1^\infty\frac{x-1}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}\log(M)+\frac1M-1=\infty$$and therefore the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{n^2}$ diverges.

Comment: Does this fine even tho the original series increasing

Comment: I applied the integral test to the decreasing series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The very simple way uses asymptotic *equivalents*:

$1-n\sim_\infty -n$, so $\dfrac{1-n}{2n^2}\sim_\infty \dfrac{-n}{2n^2}=-\dfrac 1{2n}$, and the latter diverges.

This uses the following general result from *Asymptotic analysis*:

> If two series $\sum a_n$ and \sum b_n$ have  equivalent general terms of constant sign, the both converge or both diverge

Comment: We didnt get introduced to this so I dont think will be able to use it but thanks

Comment: Strange… Here, second year students see it. This is the most efficient tool to simplify solutions by getting rid of irrelevant details.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need integral test for this series. Integral test is messy. You can just look at $\frac{n - 1}{n^2}$ you will get $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}$. Based on p series theorem, if $\frac{1}{n^p}$ where p $\leq 1$ , then the series is divergent. thus, the series you have is divergent